# np.dot(): TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType' in for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, deep-learning, typeerror, numpy-ndarray

While implementing the forward propagation algorithm from scratch, I get this error when trying to update the weighted sum, *z*, from *N* inputs and weights:

```
File "root/StandardFF/standard_feed_forward.py", line 119, in forward_propagation
    Z = np.dot(self.params['weight_' + str(layer + 1)], activation_Z) + self.params['bias_' + str(layer + 1)]
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

In my `forward_propagation` function, I define the first weighted sum parameter outside the `for`-loop:

```
    def forward_propagation(self, features_train):
        cache = {}

        # For weighted sum
        activation_Z = np.array(features_train.T)

        # Exclude the final layer
        for layer in range(self.L - 1):
            Z = np.dot(self.params['weight_' + str(layer + 1)], activation_Z) + self.params['bias_' + str(layer + 1)]
            activation_Z = self.activation(Z, self.activation_seq[layer])
            # Rest of implementation...
```

I printed `type(activation_Z)` and it was indeed a NumPy array that contains all floats, and `self.params['weight_1']` also contains floats. It looks like `activation_Z` somehow reinitializes to `None` as soon as the `for`-loop executes. Why is this happening and how can I fix this code?

Comment: Look at the *elements* of the arrays, not the arrays themselves.  For example, just because `activation_Z` is a numpy array doesn't mean it doesn't contain a `None` element.

Comment: Hint: how does `np.dot` make use of `*`? It's not `activation_Z` that's `None, but *one of its elements*. Either that, or one of the elements in the `self.params['weight_' + str(layer + 1)]`. You say that thing isn't `None` either, but again, consider its *elements*.

Comment: Sorry, had to clarify a bit more - both ```activation_Z``` and the weight_params all contained floats when I printed them out before assigning to ```Z``` in the ```for```-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your features_train contains None values. You can print it or observe it on debug mode to see what is going wrong.